# I want to pass a variable into a border radius property using LESS

Tags: css, less

I went through the LESS documentation but the examples are more complex than what I need.

Essentially I just wanted to create a border-radius property that could take an argument, that's it.

Currently I'm writing it like this but it doesn't work:

```
.border-radius(val) {
    border-radius(val);
}
```

and I'm calling it in my block like this.

```
.style {
  .border-radius(50%);
}
```

Has anyone tried to do something like this and had success with it? Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: don't you mean `.border-radius(val) { border-radius: val}` ?

Comment: The first example in [this section](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature) contains exactly the code you need... I can't image how can it be more simple than that...

Comment: And just in case before you start to write your mixins for vendor-prefixing of `border-radius` or whatever vendor-prefixed properties, discover Autoprefixer tools ([1](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer), [2](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) or whatever [else](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#usage) suitable AP wrapper for your build enviroment).

Comment: @JoelAlmeida I tried your first suggestion and that didn't work. I like your answer below it's just that I was wondering if there's a way to create this function and add a different value whenever I need to. For example I wanted to be able to call a property for border-radius like this from inside the block declaration: .border-radius(50%); But I tried with the first example and the second answer has to declare the border radius as a static initial value. I wanted to be able to add the value as an argument and pass it into the function. I know LESS can do functions just not sure of this one.

Comment: @MARS Did you actually read the docs section I linked above? You keep saying "I tried and it did not work" - while it's known to be a valid and wide used code (see [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/OVERYg?editors=110)). So could you be more specific about how you've actually tried it and what exactly did not work?

Comment: @JoelAlmeida I missed those smaller links, sorry, but yes the Parametric Mixins worked perfectly, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixins can also take arguments, which are variables passed to the block of selectors when it is mixed in.

For example, with a 4px default:

```
.border-radius(@radius: 4px) {
  -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
     -moz-border-radius: @radius;
          border-radius: @radius;
}
```

And here's how we can mix it into various rulesets:

```
#header {
   // Will get the 4px default value
  .border-radius;
}
.button {
  .border-radius(6px);
}
```

Source: http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature

Comment: This is a cool suggestion however if I needed to created 10 different border radiuses then I would have to create this class 10 times or am I mistaken? Also how would you call this class within a property block? Would it be ".border-radius(@radius:5px);" ? Thanks.

Comment: I updated your answer to use the LESS links that you provided for Parametric Mixins. Thanks.